# How to ignore the invalid data when using =rank() function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

There are some cells containing errors `#value!`. I try to use `rank(D2,D$2:D$125)` to get the ranking .But it returns `#VALUE!` because of the errors . How can I ignore those cells containing errors ?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COUNTIF`, which will ignore error values for the purpose of ranking.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(D2),COUNTIF(D$2:D$125,">"&D2)+1,"")`

Comment: But then ,for those `#VALUE!` row , it shows `1` .They should not have ranking .How to solve?

Comment: @evabb Amended the formula.